# Percentage from center in a CGRect formula

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Once I have the X,Y coordinates, what formula could I use to calculate the percentage from the center point of a CGRect with center being 0 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythagorean theorem: `a^2 + b^2 = c^2`

You have the a and b from the width and height of the CGPoint minus the width and height of the center. Solve for c, then convert to a percentage based on whatever you constraint is (you don't mention)